# Running all tests from a @Category using Maven

Tags: junit, maven, categories, surefire

I want to run only a subset of my unit tests, the ones defined by a specific `@Category`.

So I read several SO questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100924/how-to-run-junit-tests-by-category-in-maven) (which is exactly what I am looking for), and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176570/how-to-run-all-tests-belonging-to-a-certain-category-in-junit-4).

The solution of my problem seems to be provided by the [ClasspathSuite project](http://www.johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp). So I started to write the `NewTest` and `OldTest` interfaces that will define my test categories. Then, I created the `AllTests` suite:

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
public class AllTests { }
```

After that, I created a `AllNewTests` suite:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(NewTest.class)
@SuiteClasses( { AllTests.class })
public class AllNewTests { }
```

Finally, I create two JUnit classes, one per category:

```
@Category(NewTest.class)
public class SomeNewTests {
    // some tests...
}

@Category(OldTest.class)
public class SomeOldTests {
    // some tests...
}
```

---

Now, if I run **AllTests**, Eclipse launches all the tests of my project, while Maven fails as no test are found:

```
mvn test -Dtest=AllTests

...
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running my.company.AllTests
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.093 sec
There are no tests to run.
```

If I run **AllNewTests** (which is the correct thing to do, right?), in Eclipse everything is fine (i.e. it only run the tests annoted with `@Category(NewTest.class)`) but **Maven returns an error**:

```
mvn test -Dtest=AllNewTests

...
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running my.company.AllNewTests
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.125 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error:
  initializationError(my.company.AllNewTests)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The exception thrown is the following:

```
org.junit.runner.manipulation.NoTestsRemainException
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:256)
    at org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.<init>(Categories.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

---

**My question is what I did wrong?**

---

Technical details: Java 6, Maven 3.0.2, JUnit 4.8.1, Surefire plugin 2.7.1, cpsuite-1.2.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an update: as of Surefire plugin v2.11, JUnit 4.8+ style categories are now supported.

The [release notes for Surefire v2.11](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10541&version=17856) mention the new feature.  The surefire:test goal can is configured using [groups](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups).

Comment: Have you actually succeeded in doing this ? I'm can't seem to make it work. Surefire (2.11 / 2.12) seem to ignore the groups. It simply runs all tests.

Comment: @JanGoyvaerts This was a bug and is now fixed. In fact, to run the categories in 2.11 and 2.12, you have to specify a dependency on the junit 47 provider (surefire-junit47). This is fixed in 2.13-SNAPSHOT, and should work without the explicit dependency.

Comment: I've made it work in the end as you said. BUT ... there's a big performance problem with the provider. It buffers the logs (that's not too bad) and eats all memory and cpu when the tests last too long. So I switched to the naming convention - as it was meant to be originally. That works without a problem. I've signaled the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved my problem by creating my own `JUnit Runner`, that extends the `Suite`.

The idea is close to the principle by the Classpath Suite project, i.e. looking for the classes existing in the classpath, and keep only the ones that are annotated with a given annotation (`@NewTest` for example).

If you are interested, you can read the [full story on my blog](http://linsolas.free.fr/wordpress/index.php/2011/02/how-to-categorize-junit-tests-with-maven/).

Comment: This method is now completely obsolete, with the evolutions made in surefire plugin (see user1034382 answer).

Answer (score 1):

After reading some blog posts and stackoverflow questions, I finally was able to make this work with the surefire plugin, as user1034382 answered. In my case with version 2.17 of maven-surefire-plugin.

Just to add my two cents, the more up-to-date explanation can be found here:
[Using JUnit Categories to group tests](http://www.lintips.com/?q=node/173)

But you may run with the following surefire plugin problem:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load category:
```

That can be fixed with this other stackoverflow question/answer:
[Where should I put interface class for Junit @Category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981320/where-should-i-put-interface-class-for-junit-category)

My answer is just to gather all these info here and avoid googling/reading to many diferent solutions. Al least, this worked to me.