# How can I boost the Integration build using Maven

Tags: maven

I have around 20 modules need to built and how I could achieve this in faster way using maven 2.0+

Currently my build starts from root pom.xml using hudson
just calls mvn clean install

I do not want to skip any of the unit tests as well.

Currently it is taking almost an hour.Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running Maven 3? Maybe you can run your unit/integration tests parellelized? What is the bottleneck of the build? integration test/compile/generating ?

Answer (score 2):

Wish I had more "high tech" suggestion but I would start by splitting tests into two groups:

1. "Fast" ones which will be part of every build and
2. "Slow" ones which will be part of "Slow" build. The "Slow" build is run several times a day.

Usually, unit tests are fast and become part of the "Fast" build while integration tests are part of the "Slow" build.

I would be careful with parallel tests: they can create more problems than they solves.

You can read more on integration test implementation in Maven here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing

Answer (score 1):

What [Sasha O said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670525/how-can-i-boost-the-integration-build-using-maven/5671294#5671294) is really important. If your build takes so much times, maybe your tests are not simple **unit**  tests. So splitting the tests among two categories will be a good idea. Your fast tests should be real unit tests, which means that they should not involve Spring context, important disk I/O, or real database connection (you can use in-memory database, such as H2 or HSQLDB).

If you are using **TestNG** for your tests, you can use the [groups feature](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) to split your tests. If you are using **JUnit**, the [`@Category`](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0) can be useful. Using JUnit, this `@Category` is not perfect, and [it was a problem for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970196/running-all-tests-from-a-category-using-maven). I solve my problem by [creating a custom JUnit Runner](http://linsolas.free.fr/wordpress/index.php/2011/02/how-to-categorize-junit-tests-with-maven/) (the solution is not perfect neither, but can be helpful).

Another advice: maybe you could consider using a better hardware for your continuous integration server. Indeed, compilation and tests execution can be really improved by using a computer with better performances. As well, if you are not using a recent JDK, you may migrate to JDK 1.6 for example...

Finally, there is an interesting option with Maven since version 2.1: the **incremental build**. This option is available when you click on the "Advanced" button of the Maven build options if you are using Hudson / Jenkins.

The principle is to build only the modules that are impacted by your changes (i.e. commits). Let's take an example. I have this project:

```
project
  +- commons
  +- persistence
  +- business
```

The `business` project is dependent on `persistence`, which is dependent on `commons`. Now, if you have a commit on the `persistence` project, why would you need to compile, test and package `commons`, as this project did not change? The `incremental build` option will only rebuild the modified project, as well as the dependent modules. In my example, `persistence` will be rebuilt, as well as `business`.

Comment: Hi romaintaz,Thanks for the valuable input how to configure incremental build in Hudson?