# Is there a way to force Maven Surefire or JUnit to indicate the name of the failing test class when executed from a Test Suite?

Tags: java, maven, junit, surefire, test-suite

My question: Is there a way to force Maven Surefire (or JUnit?) to indicate the name of the failing test class when this class has been executed from a Test Suite?

Now, the *long* story.

Imagine you have a JUnit test suite that launches two JUnit tests.

Examples of test classes:

```
public class TestOne {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void bar() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

}

@UnitTest
public class TestTwo {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        assertFalse(true);
    }

}
```

and the test suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(value = { TestOne.class, TestTwo.class })
public class MySuite {

}
```

Now, if I run the test suite (`mvn test -Dtest=MySuite`), I will have the following errors:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running caf.opm.preclosing.junit.MySuite
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:
  foo(my.project.junit.TestOne)
  bar(my.project.junit.TestOne)
  foo(my.project.junit.TestTwo)

Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

So reading these lines, I can easily detect which classes and tests are failing.

However, in `target/surefire-reports/` directory, I have only one file, `MySuite.txt` where the three tests are failing.
One of the consequences of such situation is that my Hudson build will show me the following information:

```
All Failed Tests
Test Name       Duration    Age   
>>> my.project.junit.MySuite.foo    0.0 1
>>> my.project.junit.MySuite.bar    0.0 1
>>> my.project.junit.MySuite.foo    0.0 1
```

As you can see, it becomes harder to identify the failing tests, and for example, as `TestOne.foo()` and `TestTwo.foo()` failed, I saw two `MySuite.foo` errors in my JUnit report.
Of course I can retrieve the name of the test class by reading the logs of the failed test, but it's not really a solution...

So my question is to know if I can force Surefire (or JUnit?) to indicate the name of test class.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use a custom `TestSuite` - can you have Hudson/Maven simply execute *all* of the tests? The default behavior in the test phase would execute all tests, and report on them as you would expect.

Comment: Which version of the surefire plugin do you use? Based on my experience there should be supplemental files in the surefire-reports folder...

Comment: Why are you using a suite? Why not let surefire do the work...

Comment: @matt b and @khmarbaise If you really want to understand why I need to run a `suite`, read the whole story here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970196/running-all-tests-from-a-category-using-maven

Comment: I just did a try with Surefire 2.8, but with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I get a single file per test class, so it took me a moment to figure this one out: You're using a test suite.

When using test suites, all the test results end up in a single file with the name of the suite.

There is no option to change this behavior. Try to [file a feature request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE).