# Is it possible to generate individual failsafe-reports for classes mentioned in TestSuite?

Tags: maven, junit, test-suite, maven-failsafe-plugin

Is it possible to generate individual failsafe-reports for classes mentioned in TestSuite? Because right now its generating only one failsafe report for whole TestSuite.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a way to force Maven Surefire or JUnit to indicate the name of the failing test class when executed from a Test Suite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033742/is-there-a-way-to-force-maven-surefire-or-junit-to-indicate-the-name-of-the-fail). The answer, which is a few years old, is "No".