# Group test in JUnit and specify which to run in Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run junit tests by category in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100924/how-to-run-junit-tests-by-category-in-maven)

I have a question regarding grouping tests in JUnit.

I have got a test class annotated with

```
@Category(IntegrationTests.class)
public class TestClass { ... }
```

And IntegrationTests is just an interface.

Is there anyway I can specify in maven command line that only run this category of test?

Many thanks.

Comment: Duplicate question : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html
Look at this link for all possible test cases

Answer (score 4):

The difference between unit tests and integration test is simple the [naming convention](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes):

```
**/Test*.java
**/*Test.java
**/*TestCase.java
```

will be recognized as unit tests. And the integration test based on [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) will be recognized by a different naming convention:

```
**/IT*.java
**/*IT.java
**/*ITCase.java
```

Comment: Note this is the default, and can be overriden by custom rules or annotation Categories in Junit > 4.8

Answer (score 2):

Why not rely on existing conventions?

`mvn clean test` will run unit tests via surefire.
`mvn clean verify` will run integration tests via failsafe

You can use naming conventions or annotations to enforce selection.

```
thisIsAUnitTest.java will be executed by surefire (mvn test)
thisClassIsAnIT.java will be executed by failsafe (mvn verify)
```

HOW ?!

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/

### SureFire for Unit Tests

**By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:**

```
"**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "Test".
"**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test".
"**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "TestCase".
```

### Failsafe for integratino tests

**By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:**

```
"**/IT*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "IT".
"**/*IT.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "IT".
"**/*ITCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "ITCase".
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know this. How can I specify which tests are integration test so that they are not run when I run "maven clean install"?

Comment: Either categories http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories  Or naming convention.  I have added a bunch of details and examples above.