# Tell Eclipse to skip tests

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, maven-2

Is there a way to tell only `Eclipse`  to skip various individual `junit` tests (but still run the rest of them)? I am familiar with the `@Ignore` annotation, but that is not what I am looking for because that will cause the tests to **always** be skipped.

I would like the tests to be skipped when ran by eclipse (`Run As -> Junit Test`) but ran in any other context, most likely during a maven build.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to control which tests are run/skipped in maven and Eclipse using [JUnit 4 categories](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html). There is some discussion of this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100924/how-to-run-junit-tests-by-category-in-maven

Comment: @nbrooks I found a different solution for now but categories were good to learn about. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far the following solution has worked well. It is not a complete solution because it causes the tests to only be ran by maven *when maven is invoked from the command line*. For now though, it works.

When maven is invoked, the maven command line arguments are placed in the environment map (`System.getenv()`). When the tests are run through jUnit in eclipse, there is no entry in `System.getenv()` for the maven command line arguments. So, I am using jUnits `Assume` class to check that this property is not null for the tests that I want eclipse to skip.

Code:

```
Assume.assumeNotNull(System.getenv("MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS"));
```

FYI, one downside of this solution is that eclipse marks the tests as *passed* instead of *skipped*.