# How to run Categorized Junit tests using Gradle?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, test-suite

My Question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100924/how-to-run-junit-tests-by-category-in-maven), but it refers to `Gradle` not `Maven`.

I have marked several tests within my project with the `@Category` annotation, and created my Test Suite (See below).

How do I run this using Gradle?

**Test Suite:**

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(MyTestSuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(ClassUnderTest.class)
public interface MyTestSuite {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you need something like this, according to JUnit [wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories):

> Gradle's test task allows the specification of the JUnit categories
>   you want to include and exclude.
>
> ```
> test {
>     useJUnit {
>         includeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryA'
>         excludeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
>     }
> }
> ```

Configuration above is example of global tests configuration, but you can create a custom test task to run specific test categories, as follows:

```
task customTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'some.package.name.MyTestSuite'
    }
}
```