# How to run unit tests in excludedGroups in Maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

I have a JUnit 4.12 `SlowTests` test suite that I want to exclude from execution unless specifically requested on the Maven command line.

I have added the following to my pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludedGroups>com.Example.SlowTests</excludedGroups>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*TestSuite.class</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude></exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have defined the category as `SlowTests` and applied it to the `MySlowTests` class.

I have annotated the test suite as follows:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(SlowTests.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MySlowTests.class })
public class MySlowTestSuite
```

When I run `mvn package` all the unit tests except `MySlowTests` are executed.

However, looking at various answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/25639372/820657 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21830866/820657 I expected the following command:

```
mvn package -Dgroups=com.Example.MySlowTests
```

to run the excluded `MySlowTests` tests but they don't run. In fact no tests run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maven Surefire plugin has some issues w.r.t categories in versions < 2.13 (IIRC) but as long as you are using Surefire >= 2.13 the following will run any classes annotated with `@Category(com.yourcompany.SlowTests.class)`:

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>
      <configuration>
        <groups>com.yourcompany.SlowTests</groups>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This approach is often used with profiles, the following configuration ...

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>slow</id>
        <properties>
            <testCategories>com.yourcompany.SlowTests</testCategories>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>fast</id>
        <properties>
            <testCategories>com.yourcompany.FastTests</testCategories>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>${testCategories}</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

... can be used to run:

- `mvn install -P slow`: runs the slow tests only
- `mvn install -P fast`: runs the fast tests only
- `mvn install -P fast,slow`: runs the fast and slow tests

**Update 1:** for this question: *"Is there a way to use this approach so I can run all fast tests by default?"*

You can define two properties:

```
<properties>
    <includedCategories></includedCategories>
    <excludedCategories>com.yourcompany.SlowTests</excludedCategories>
</properties>
```

Then update your surefire plugin definition like so:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <configuration>
            <groups>${includedCategories}</groups>
            <excludedGroups>${excludedCategories}</excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And, finally, add this profile:

```
    <profile>
        <id>slow</id>
        <properties>
            <includedCategories>com.yourcompany.SlowTests</includedCategories>
            <excludedCategories></excludedCategories>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

This just toggles the `includedCategories` and `excludedCategories` properties. By default, you **include** everything except those tests annotated with `com.yourcompany.SlowTests` (i.e. everything except your 'slow' tests). When you run with `-P slow` you **exclude** everything except those tests annotated with `com.yourcompany.SlowTests` (i.e. everything except your 'slow' tests).

Note: what I said in my original answer about Surefire versions < 2.13 misbehaving with Categories still stands so to make this work you need to be using a version of the Maven Surefire plugin >= 2.13.

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach so I can run all fast tests by default? I don't want to have to annotate all my fast test suites.

Comment: @ksl I have updated the answer to include implementation details for that requirement.