# How to split JUnit Tests in a Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, categories

I am trying to split my tests using Junit categories for Jenkins. I read all the guides online and did the following.

1. Created an interface

```
public interface regression {}
```

2. Added annotation to test

```
    @Category(regression.class)
    @Test
    public void myTest(){}
```

3. Added the group to POM.XML

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>test_listener.TestListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <groups>categories.regression</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I wrote the following terminal:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=categories.regression
```

and received this error message:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project automation: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try running the command again, but using `-Dgroups=categories.regression` instead of `-Dtest`

Also, check out:

- [How to run JUnit tests by category in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100924/how-to-run-junit-tests-by-category-in-maven)
- [Run a single test method with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven)